# How can I JOIN in 3 Tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, one-to-many, entity-relationship

[image: Database Schema]

Hi, I need your help.

I have this database schema and I want to make a "select" to return all "products" where brands.brand_slug = "*acer*" and categories.category_slug = "*laptop*".
For example, I want a list of all products made by Acer in the Laptops category.

I tried with this command line, but obviously I received a list of all laptops produced by all manufacturers...

**How should I proceed?**

```
SELECT products.product_slug,
products.product_description,
products.product_img,
products.product_is_on_top,
products.product_title
FROM products
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories ON products.category=categories.category_slug
LEFT OUTER JOIN brand_category ON categories.category_slug=brand_category.category_slug
LEFT OUTER JOIN brands ON brand_category.brand_slug=brands.brand_slug
WHERE brands.brand_slug= "acer"
AND categories.category_slug="laptop"
```

Comment: Use inner joins instead of outer joins.

Comment: I tried, but the same result (returns the list with all laptop products of all manufacturers). I think he does this because he doesn't know which product belongs to which manufacturer. There is a **"ManytoMany"** relationship between "brands" and "categories" and there is a **"OneToMany"** relationship between "categories" and "products".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT products.product_slug,
products.product_description,
products.product_img,
products.product_is_on_top,
products.product_title
FROM products
INNER JOIN categories ON products.category=categories.category_slug
INNER JOIN brand_category ON categories.category_slug=brand_category.category_slug
INNER JOIN brands ON brand_category.brand_slug=brands.brand_slug
WHERE brands.brand_slug= 'acer'
AND categories.category_slug='laptop'
```

Comment: I tried, but the same result (returns the list with all laptop products of all manufacturers). I think he does this because he doesn't know which product belongs to which manufacturer. There is a **"ManytoMany"** relationship between "brands" and "categories" and there is a **"OneToMany"** relationship between "categories" and "products".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    orderNumber,
    orderDate,
    orderLineNumber,
    productName,
    quantityOrdered,
    priceEach
FROM
    orders
INNER JOIN
    orderdetails USING (orderNumber)
INNER JOIN
    products USING (productCode)
ORDER BY 
    orderNumber, 
    orderLineNumber;
```